# What's the best way to provide help for multiple questions?

Tags: discussion, canonical

There are many questions on SO to do with sprite collision and contact detection in iOS. Most are slight variations on one another and are caused by the OP not setting up their environment correctly.

I've written a function that, when called, will print out which objects are set up to collide with which others and the same for contact detection.

What's the best way to let people know of this function, other than by posting it on every question on this subject? It's not an answer to the question, but should help people see where they are going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new question and self-answer that.

Make sure the post is of excellent quality, else you will get downvoted quickly. Don't only care for the answer, but as much for the question too.

A good example is [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/993547)

Optionally, some mediocre questions can be closed as duplicate of your canonical answer, but you would need the support and approval of the community of that tag.